# Patterns for loading default data when unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Looking for some strategies for how you guys are loading default data when doing unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's people. I have been using the Builder pattern for some time and enjoyed Jan Van Ryswyck update at http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/26/test-data-builders-refined/ have a look at ObjectMother pattern and ndepend too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a builder that contains the default values, just like this: http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/26/test-data-builders-refined/. Then the test only specifies the value it cares for:

```
Customer customer = new CustomerBuilder()
   .WithFirstName("this test only cares about a special ' ... first name value");
```

After reading the other answers, I want to clear that its not for database data. Its to build the instances/data you pass to the classes you are unit testing.

Its a matter of convenience/keeping the tests simple, plenty of times you are testing very specific behavior that depends on 1-3 fields and you don't care about the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing I generally don't load data in advance - each test is designed to work against a data source that may or may not already contain existing records, and so each test writes all any records that are needed to complete the test.

When choosing values to submit to the database I use GUIDs (or other random values) whenever possible as it guarantees that values in the database are unique (e.g. if you create someone named "Mr X Y", it is helpful to **know** that searching for "X" should return only 1 result, and that there is no chance you have chanced on someone else in the database whose last name *happens* to be Y)

Often when unit testing I'm testing methods that modify data alongside methods that read data, and so my unit tests use the same API (the one being tested) to write to the database. (It's *nice* if each unit test covers a specific area of functionality, but it's not absolutely necessary)

If the API being tested doesn't have methods to write to the database however, I write my own set of helper functions - the exact structure is going to depend on the data source, but as an example this is where I often use LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred strategy is in-transaction data. Spring offers extensive [support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html) (for both JUnit 3 and 4). With this strategy your test begins brand new transaction each time and your data is rolled back at the end of test.

Of course sometimes it's not enough: either data set is too extensive and shared across tests, or multiple transactions are part of the test scope. In that case, I recommend creating shared test data bed that is created before running test suite. There are frameworks for this (dbUnit) but you can also do without them if careful and consistent.

UPD: creating in-transaction data doesn't mean you not need test data, you are likely to end up creating re-usable and shared helper classes to maintain test data in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is about testing a piece of code in **isolation**. One create an instance of a class with its dependencies (or mocks of them), call the method under test and assert to verify the outcome of the test.

Usually with TDD one starts with a simple test, without data. When data are needed, they are created in the test fixture (the isolated environment where the test is executed) by the test `setUp()` method and then destroyed by the `tearDown()` method after the test has been run. Data are not loaded from  the database.

Comment: that's fine for simple scenarios, once you start needing to build various instances or have one that's needed in various tests setUp & tearDown fall short.

Comment: @eglasius : unit tests as written with TDD, are supposed to be simple scenarios, in the Arrange-Act-Assert form ; one fixture is shared by all test in a suite, and can be modified in the Arrange section of the test. Having too much to create in setup can be a design smell.

Comment: sure, but there are processes that by nature work with some data. We are talking about data used in processes/logic here, a customer instance is something that doesn't tend to be used in a single place ;)

Answer (score 0):

I typically have methods like GetCustomer() that return a generic customer.  If I need to make the returned customer suite my needs for a particular test, I will simply change the property after it gets returned.

Other times I may pass some configuration information into my GetCustomer() method. For example GetCustomer(string customerType).

I've read expert's opinions that says that each test should contain its own unique data to work with and not try to make the data generic.  Even though this may make each test "larger" in size, over all it will make the test clearer because the setup is specific to each test and the goals of each test.  I like this advice because I've ran into many cases where trying to make the setup data generic, made things very sloppy very quick.